# Two files fail MD5SUM checks on Ubuntu 15.10 USB disk

Tags: live-usb, 15.10

I created a USB stick with Ubuntu 15.10 64bit, using Universal USB Installer. If I run the MD5SUMS integrity check, I get these two errors:

```
./boot/grub/grub.cfg: FAILED
./boot/grub/loopback.cfg: FAILED
md5sum: WARNING: 2 computed checksums did NOT match
```

Is this expected?

I've tried two USB sticks so far, so I don't think it's an issue with the USB stick. I've also tried extracting the .iso file and checking the MD5SUMs there, and it does not fail, it seems Universal USB Installer modifies these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this too using Ubuntu 15.04's built-in Startup Disk Creator and the 15.10 ISO.

The changes are deliberate. They appear to be boot options which the Grub bootloader must pass to the Linux kernel to enable it to boot from external media (CD or USB) rather than an internal hard drive.

For example, compare line 3 from the file `./boot/grub/loopback.cfg` in a text editor.

From the ISO image:

```
   linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash ---
```

From the USB flash drive created with Startup Disk Creator:

```
   linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --- cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt
```

The lines are identical except **`cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt`** was added, and the same is true for all the other lines that have changed in both `loopback.cfg` and `grub.cfg`. This is an option for the Linux kernel to allow booting from USB or CD instead of an internal HDD [1].

On a side note, these changes were deliberate but it is possible for errors or corruptions to occur during the ISO download or writing to CD/USB. However, the probability of errors occurring is proportional to the file size [2], so you are much more likely to see bit errors or corruptions in larger files (a few GBs in size) than in small files like these (~1kB each). Also, the new files are slightly larger than the originals, but errors are more likely to result in bits being flipped or missed rather than new bits added.

[1] - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB

[2] - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM